# CLLocationManager fails to get the user's location in device but not in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I'm using a CLLocationManager for a GPS tracking system in my iOS app. The app works fine with the debug feature of the simulator but once the build is in the device, it fails to do so. Giving me an error, "Failed to get location." This is how I did it:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
```

then the startupdating is in a uibutton. Any help will be gravely appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: On simulater it take only default location not your current location.

Comment: Has the device enabled location services globally and has your app permissions on the device?

Comment: Is it possible for the app to be working on the simulator but not on the device? I kind of concluded that my method works since it managed to get the outcome I wanted in the simulator. But not in the iPhone.

Comment: Yes, I checked it in location services. The app is permitted to find the user's location.

Comment: Either your device should have connectivity or it should be in open space to get location..

Comment: My iPhone is connected to the router, I just checked it. The weird thing is that it was working fine earlier but then it doesn't work now. That was also the case last week. I left it for 3 days then bam, working again this morning.

Comment: check the error in "locationManager:didFailWithError:" method when its not  working. post it here , that will help .

Comment: I don't know how to do that, the error comes only when the phone is unplugged from the computer.

Comment: Paste your full source code above..

Answer (score 1):

First setup the location manager

```
 locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And after that call delegate method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"lat%f - lon%f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);

    currentLocationCoordinate.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
    currentLocationCoordinate.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Address Found" object:self];

}
```

this is work for me . it will help you